# Configuring multiple proxies on one server

Tags: proxy, squid

Let's say we have 3 laptops, each needing a proxy server in order to bypass a firewall restriction.  We need each laptop to have a different IP when accessing 3rd party websites.

One way to do this is to set up 3 different proxy servers running squid, each with a different IP, on a service such as Amazon AWS.  But this is wasteful and cumbersome to manage 3 servers.

It is possible to do from one machine?  Can you somehow buy multiple IPs and then connect them to one squid instance?